# Get the row with latest start date from multiple tables using sub select

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, subquery

I have data from 3 tables as copied below . I am not using joins to get data. I dont know how to use joins for multiple tables scenario. My situation is to update the OLD(eff_start_ts) date rows to sydate in one of the tables when we find the rows returned for a particular user is more than 2. `enter code here`

```
subscription_id |Client_id
----------------------------
20685413        |37455837
```

```
reward_account_id|subscription_id   |CURRENCY_BAL_AMT   |CREATE_TS |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
439111697        | 20685413         |   -40             |1-09-10   |
```

```
REWARD_ACCT_DETAIL_ID|REWARD_ACCOUNT_ID |EFF_START_TS   |EFF_STOP_TS |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
230900968           |   439111697       |   14-06-11    | 15-01-19  
47193932            |   439111697       |   19-02-14    | 19-12-21  
243642632           |   439111697       |   18-03-23    | 99-12-31  
247192972           |   439111697       |   17-11-01    | 17-11-01
```

The SQL should update the EFF_STOP_TS of last table except the second row - 47193932 bcz that has the latest EFF_START_TS.

Expected result is to update the EFF_STOP_TS  column of 230900968, 243642632 and 247192972 to sysdate.

Comment: Please post your sample data, expected result as text not as image.

Comment: Edited.. Please advise.

Comment: _"Edited.. Please advise."_    Um ... "as text not as image"   And please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You need to update it per REWARD_ACCOUNT_ID. So, You can try the below code -

```
UPDATE REWARD_ACCT_DETAIL RAD
   SET EFF_STOP_TS = SYSDATE
 WHERE EFF_START_TS NOT IN (SELECT MAX(EFF_START_TS)
                              FROM REWARD_ACCT_DETAIL RAD1
                             WHERE RAD.REWARD_ACCOUNT_ID = RAD1.REWARD_ACCOUNT_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit.. Will try doing this way